# Save json to ADLS Gen2 using the Azure Synapse Copy Activity with content type application json

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm using Azure Synapse REST api source in copy activity and trying to save api response as json with `content-type` as `application/json` in a azure data lake gen2 storage container. After saving the json documents I see the `content-type` set to `application/octet-stream`. How do I save the `content-type` as `application/json`?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- One way you can achieve this requirement is by using Azure data lake storage Rest API. Refer to this [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/filesystem/set-properties) where you can see the rest API and how you can authorize to access the Rest API.
- You can use web activity to Call the required REST API with authentication and try to set the required content type.
- Another approach would be to use Azure logic apps to create the file with required content and content-type.
- Let's say you have used copy data activity to write the response to a JSON file (op.json) where content-type is `application/octet-stream`. Now, using the flow as shown in the below image:

[image]

- The final result would be a JSON as shown below:

[image]